# iText Java - Can't get the image show on pdf on html header

Tags: java, image, itext

I am following this example [HtmlHeaderFooter.java](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/page-events-headers-and-footers#1331-htmlheaderfooter.java)
for creating a pdf file that has the same header and footers on each page but for some reason i can't get the image to display on pdf. It's just blank where it needs to show the image.

I tried moving the image on every single folder in case it's a path issue but no luck on that either.

Here is an example of my code below.

```
package amt.view.PDF.section0;

 import amt.Methods;
 import com.itextpdf.text.*;
 import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;
 import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.*;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.SQLException;


 public class section0 {



     static String Customer;
     static String CustomerTitle;
     static String RefNo;
     static String Revision;
     static String RefNoTitle;
     public static String DEST;
     public static final String UserDesktop = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";

     static String selectedID = "1";

     public static void getVariables() throws SQLException {
         Connection c = Methods.chooseConnection();
         String SQL = "SELECT * FROM preset_values WHERE ID LIKE '" + selectedID + "'";
         ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
         while (rs.next()) {
             Customer = rs.getString("Customer");
             RefNo = rs.getString("Reference_No");
             CustomerTitle = rs.getString("Customer").replace(" ", "_");
             RefNoTitle = rs.getString("Reference_No").replace(" ", "_");
             Revision = rs.getString("Revision");
         }
         DEST = UserDesktop + "/" + CustomerTitle + "-" + RefNoTitle + "_Rev-" + Revision + ".pdf";

     }


     public static final String HEADER = "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\"><tr><td><img src=\"logo.png\" /></td><td align=\"right\">Some title</td></tr></table>";
     public static final String FOOTER = "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\"><tr><td>Footer</td><td align=\"right\">Some title</td></tr></table>";


     public class HeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {

         protected ElementList header;
         protected ElementList footer;

         public HeaderFooter() throws IOException {
             header = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(HEADER, "../headerfooter.css");
             footer = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(FOOTER, null);
         }

         @
         Override
         public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
             try {
                 ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
                 ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(36, 832, 559, 810));
                 header.stream().forEach((e) - > {
                     ct.addElement(e);
                 });
                 ct.go();
                 ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(36, 10, 559, 32));
                 footer.stream().forEach((e) - > {
                     ct.addElement(e);
                 });
                 ct.go();
             } catch (DocumentException de) {
                 throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
             }
         }
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException, SQLException {
         getVariables();
         File file = new File(DEST);
         file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
         new section0().createPdf(DEST);
     }

     public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
         // step 1
         Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 36, 72);
         // step 2
         PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
         writer.setPageEvent(new HeaderFooter());
         // step 3
         document.open();
         // step 4
         for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
             document.add(new Paragraph(Customer + "\n" + RefNo));
         // step 5
         document.close();
     }
 }
```

Comment: I wrote that example in answer to a specific question. When I wrote that example, it was my opinion that it was a bad idea to use HTML to define the header and the footer. I still think it's a bad idea. My counter-question is: did you use that bad idea because you found that example, or do you have a very specific reason to use that bad idea. Is it an option to define the header and footer using ordinary iText code?

Comment: By the way: the reason why your image doesn't show is simple: there is no file named `logo.png` in the working directory of your application. The path is wrong and you didn't write an `ImageProvider` to fix this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bruno, the reason i wanted to use HTML is because i am better at it than I am at java. I just couldn't find a way to make an image at left and address at right of the header with java. Maybe if you could show me a simple example of it, that would really help. 
Thank you in advance @BrunoLowagie

Comment: That's not a matter of knowing Java; that's a matter of knowing iText. See [How to add a table as a header?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-table-header) and add an image to a cell, as done in the [IconDescriptionTable](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/adding-images-table#1444-icondescriptiontable.java) example.

Comment: Thank you very much Bruno, the links you've provided did the trick for me. Many thanks :) @BrunoLowagie